# Do I have to pay duty to carry nutritional supplements with me?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, local-customs, duty-free

I am going to travel India from UK next month and I am thinking to carry nutritional supplements with me. The items I want to carry are:

1. Whey Protein : 5KG
2. BCAA: 1 KG
3. Glutamine: 500grams
4. L-Citruline Mallate: 100 Grams
5. Cretine: 1KG
6. L-Arginine: 100 grams
7. Beta alanine: 100grams

I am an Indian national and returning home after completing my studies.

All the supplements are in powder form and all together cost around £62. I am buying it from myprotein.com because of genuine and low price. I am wondering do I have to duty fee at airport or not.

I have contacted to customer care of myprotein and they said usually if you carry supplements with you there are less chance they will stop you for customs but they were not 100% sure.

Please advice me about this or the sources where I can get more information about this,.

Comment: I can't vouch for the site, but [his site](http://www.cybex.in/indian-custom-duty/default.aspx) has the gov't regulations on what products are dutiable, in what quantities and the charge, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't £62 be under the duty free allowance anyway?  Unless there is specific non-exempt duty on these otherwise random products.

Answer (score 1):

India levies various [duties on imported nutritional supplements](http://www.cybex.in/indian-custom-duty/details.aspx?PRODUCT=food%20supplements), ranging from as low as 10% up to 150% on some products, under the authority of the Central Board of Excise and Customs.

As noted, you may not be charged for small amounts intended for personal use, along with your belongings as you return from studies abroad. But, as you may also know, with a significant market in India for such products, you may owe duty, the very reason that web sites such as [myprotein has estimates](https://www.myprotein.co.in/customer-services/delivery-information.list) of  customs and import duties.